# pycharm matplotlib window (python) issue

Tags: matplotlib, ubuntu, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm.  (I was happy with the Spyder IDE, but it has unacceptable memory leaks.)  Anyway, when I make a plot in an iPython console [e.g., plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,66),'ko') ],
it make a window with the expected plot, but I can't use any other window until I close the plot window.  Anybody know what could be causing this?   Also, I was unable to find the settings for the iPython console (I would like it run some import statements when it opens)

I did a simple plotting command, and I was expecting the plot window to stay open while I do things in other windows.  But I was unable to work in other windows (PyCharm or other apps) until I closed the plot window

Answer (score 0):

that's only available in the professional (commercial) version of pycharm, specifically the [scientific mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html).

an open source alternative is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it will open the plots in a second window when you run the scripts in interactive mode.

Comment: I'll see if it works in the pro version.  configuring Visual Studio to work with python interactively with my anaconda installation sounds rather painful.

Answer (score 0):

For a while I had it working when I changed the backend using the command: matplotlib.use('QT5Agg') , which changes the backend.  It was using the 'MacOSX' backend before.  But I can't get it working again.  Don't know why.  I'm on Ubuntu, btw.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).